# Sass division isn't a valid CSS value

Tags: css, sass

I have a Sass variable

```
// Space unit
$base-space-unit:       1em !default;
```

If i do multiplication it works like this

```
.pads           { padding: 5*$base-space-unit; }
```

and returns

```
.pads { padding: 5em; }
```

But if i did division like this

```
.pads           { padding: 5/$base-space-unit; }
```

i get

```
Syntax error: 5/em isn't a valid CSS value.
```

What could be wrong with this.

Comment: no idea of why this happen, but you could solve by writing `$base-space-unit: 1 !default`;

Comment: What would 5/1em get you anyway? It's not a logical calculation.

Comment: @Paulie_D if you try to do 5em / 1em (try on http://sassmeister.com/) you obtain `5` instead of `5em`

Comment: So what does 5 get you...I'm confused? In any case, that's not the calculation attempted...maybe `5em/$base-space-unit;` would work although I'm not seeing a use.

Comment: The case is that I want to get the division of 5/16 so i can evaluate the formula that says target/context = result, bu i was setting the context to 1 instead of 16. but this syntax works for me .pads           { padding: (5/16*$base-space-unit);} and the result is .pads { padding: 0.3125em; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The case is that I want to get the division of 5/16 so i can evaluate the formula that says

```
target/context = result
```

but i was setting the context to 1 instead of 16.

this syntax works for me as

```
.pads { padding: (5/16*$base-space-unit);}
```

and the result is

```
.pads { padding: 0.3125em; }
```

Thanks